# How we show description in virtuemart feature product module in joomla?

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I want to show feature product description on the frontpage.I am using VirtueMart Featured Products Module to show feature products.can any one suggest me what i have to do to display description of the feature products, at the moment only product name, image and price are showning.

Comment: I have over come with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow below path and change it to display short description of Featured Products Module

```
yoursite\components\com_virtuemart\themes\virtualmarttheme-name\templates\common\productsnapshot.tpl
```